# Tracking elements of one list with respect to the other in Python

Tags: python, list

I have lists `J1` and `Ci`. For every zero element in `J1`, I want the corresponding element in `Ci` to be zero. For every non-zero element in `J1`, the corresponding element in `Ci` should be the same. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
J1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
Ci=[0.0,
 8.317333882002454e-05,
 0.0,
 8.305496451875518e-05,
 8.24723410599921e-05,
 8.257692992192182e-05,
 8.2641447034131e-05]

J1=[i for i in J1[0] if i!=0]
Ci=Ci[J1]
print(Ci)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    Ci=Ci[J1]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

The expected output is

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.257692992192182e-05, 0.0]
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a list of lists as an index to `Ci`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in one comprehension using `zip()`:

```py
J1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
Ci=[0.0,
 8.317333882002454e-05,
 0.0,
 8.305496451875518e-05,
 8.24723410599921e-05,
 8.257692992192182e-05,
 8.2641447034131e-05]

Ci = [i if j != 0 else 0.0 for i, j in zip(Ci, J1[0])]

print(Ci)
```

Output:

```py
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.257692992192182e-05, 0.0]
```

Or, using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

Ci = np.where(J1[0] != 0, Ci, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to use a list as an index for another list. This is not possible as list indices must be integers or slices.

You could loop to iterate over the elements of J1 instead, and use the index of each non-zero element to access the corresponding element in Ci. If the element in J1 is zero, set the corresponding element in Ci to zero.

```
J1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
Ci = [0.0, 8.317333882002454e-05, 0.0, 8.305496451875518e-05, 8.24723410599921e-05, 8.257692992192182e-05, 8.2641447034131e-05]

for i, val in enumerate(J1[0]):
    if val == 0:
        Ci[i] = 0.0
    else:
        Ci[i] = Ci[val-1]

print(Ci)
```